# Related search words in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a convenient way to search for related words to a term. For example, If I search for the word "washer", I should be getting related search terms like "dryer" with the lower score thank washer results, It means the washer documents must appear the first and then dryer documents. how can I do this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a synonym dictionary. Fortunately, we have machine learning models now, like "word2vec (neural net)", that can do this. You can try using open source [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) package for this.

The input to the model would be lots of text/info/articles that carries the word washer and dryer.  once you train on this, you can find closest words that are related to "washer" and use these as synonym like dictionary.

At query time, look up this dictionary and expand the query with lower weight/boost for synonyms than the actual term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! but I think this is not related to Elasticsearch, and It is not convenient to train a model of a lot of text just to relate some few words, for my case I have just a few words, and I think that I should define a list of related works like [ 'washer', 'dryer' .... ]

Comment: so you are hand curating this dictionary for a smaller set of important words? if so, are you asking for how to build the query?

Comment: what i want to do is to set  lists of related words , so If i user search for a washer , he might be interested in  dryer

Comment: one way how we do semantic search is to have an intermediate layer (in java/tomcat or python/django or nodejs) that does these kinds of NLP functions. This layer parses the incoming query and looks up this lists of related words (your dictionary) and expands with right synonyms and constructs the final query to elastic.